# How to create field name in django models with hyphen?

Tags: django, python-2.7, asterisk

I have table with name of column "call-limit".

When create field in django models:

```
   call-limit = models.IntegerField(default=1,verbose_name='call-limit')
```

I have error.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set or refer to the name of the column in your relational database from the model with the `db_column` argument:

```
call_limit = models.IntegerField(default=1, db_column='call-limit',
                                 verbose_name='call-limit')
```

But the model name in your Python code must be a valid Python identifier, so cannot contain the hyphen. Why not use `call_limit` instead?

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) for more information.

Comment: Many thanks. It is working.  call_limit = models.IntegerField(default=1, db_column='call-limit',verbose_name='call-limit')

Comment: Oh yes... fixed the answer now.